# How to get attribute of a node with a namespace in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to parse Reddit's [XML file](http://www.reddit.com/new/.xml) with javascript and im having trouble retrieving an attribute from a node with a namespace. I want to get the following URL

`<media:thumbnail url="http://f.thumbs.redditmedia.com/LdOsi1MnWuzGvbDq.jpg"/>`

What I tried so far but none of these have worked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//...XMLHttpRequest...
           var items = data.getElementsByTagName("item");

            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                var item = items[i];

                //titleNode and title work fine
                var titleNode = item.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
                var title = titleNode.firstChild.data;

                //the following don't work, they actually cause the google chrome extension to stop working :(

                //attempt 1
                thumbnail = item.getElementsByTagName('thumbnail')[0];

                //attempt 2
                thumbnail = item.getElementsByTagName('media:thumbnail')[0];

                //attempt 3    
                thumbnail = item.getElementsByTagName('media', 'thumbnail')[0];

                //attempt 4
                thumbnail = item.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'thumbnail')[0];

                //attempt 5
                thumbnail = item.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'thumbnail')[0].getAttriubte("url");

                //attempt 6
                thumbnail = item.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'thumbnail')[0].firstChild.data;

                document.write(thumbnail);
            }
</script>
```

I'm lost can you offer any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.getElementsByTagName('media:thumbnail')
```

worked for me =) [In Chrome] Though I should note that on the particular XML file you referenced, the first few items do not contain `<media:thumbnail>` tags.

You should check the length of the result of the call to `getElementsByTagName` *BEFORE* trying to pull out the nth (or in your case the 0th) element, as that will cause an error.

e.g.

```
var thumbnail=null,mediaTs=item.getElementsByTagName('media:thumbnail');
if(mediaTs.length){
   thumbnail=mediaTs[0].getAttribute('url');
}

//Later on
if(thumbnail){
   //Do stuff with the string
}
```